# HBase REST to return json instead of xml

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, stargate

I am using HBase stargate REST API to fetch data from Hbase. I have tabel 'state' and row key '1' . When I paste below line in browser , I am getting output in xml format.

```
 http://localhost:8000/state/1 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><CellSet><Row key="MQ=="><Cell column="aW5mbzpjb2xvcg==" timestamp="1459193020823">cmVk</Cell><Cell column="aW5mbzpuYW1l" timestamp="1459192932985">TUg=</Cell></Row></CellSet>
```

How do get output in json format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_using_rest_endpoints

> You can request plain text (the default), XML , or JSON output by adding no header for plain text, or the header "Accept: text/xml" for XML or "Accept: application/json" for JSON.

Comment: Thanks Matias....what I understand , we can use curl or wget command to get expected output but what if I have to receive json data without using these tools i.e. just modifying my address..